# Как быть с ошибкой MultipleObjectsReturned при objects.get()?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

Проект на Python Django, приложение для заметок (NoteApp), с возможностью добавления (add) заметок, их обновления (update) и удаления (delete).

При попытке обновления (update) вылезает ошибка `MultipleObjectsReturned`, если использовать `.objects.get()`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно использовать `objects.filter()`, если, например, имеется несколько заметок, и нужно их обновить по отдельности? Или же можно как-то использовать `objects.get()`?

Вот models.py проекта:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Notes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.TimeField()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Вот views.py проекта:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from apps.notes.models import Notes

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    notes = Notes.objects.all()
    context = {
        "notes": notes, 
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def add_notes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        time = request.POST.get('time')
        note = Notes.objects.create(title=title, time=time)
        note.save()
    return redirect('index')

def edit_notes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        time = request.POST.get('time')
        if 'update' in request.POST:
            note = Notes.objects.get()
            note.title = title
            note.time = time
            note.save()
        if 'delete' in request.POST:
            note = Notes.objects.filter(title=title)
            note.delete()

    return redirect('index')
```

Вот urls.py:

```html
from django.urls import path
from apps.notes.views import index, add_notes, edit_notes

urlpatterns = [
path('', index, name='index'),
path('add/', add_notes, name='add_notes'),
path('edit/', edit_notes, name='edit_notes'),
]
```

Вот html страницы (одна страница):

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(50deg, lightblue, white);
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: darkblue;
}

div.main-container {
    margin: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
}

div.notes-container {
    background-color: darkblue;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}

div.edit-container {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}

h2 {
    color: grey;
}

input {
    color: black;
    background-color: bisque;
    border: 1px solid bisque;
}

input[type="text"] {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
}

input[type="time"] {
    padding: 8px;
}

input.id {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: gray;
    width: 15px;
    font-size: larger;
}

button {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        {% load static %}
        <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Notes App</h1>
        
        <div class="main-container">

            <h2>Add a new note:</h2>

            <div class="notes-container">

                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add_notes' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required>
                    <input type="time" name="time" required>
                    <button type="submit" name="add">Add</button>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="main-container">

            <h2>Edit a note:</h2>

            {% for  note in notes %}
            <div class="edit-container">

                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit_notes' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ note.id }}">
                    <input class="id" name="id" value="{{ forloop.counter }}">
                    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ note.title }}" required>
                    <input type="time" name="time" value="{{ note.time|time:'H:i'}}" required>
                    <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
                </form>

            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```